# Element-wise (or pointwise) comparison notation?

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there a notation for element-wise comparisons? For example, I have two vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$. I want to define $\mathbf{v}_1$ is element-wise greater than $\mathbf{v}_2$, is it ok to use $\mathbf{v}_1 > \mathbf{v}_2$?

Comment: In some contexts, this is called domination.

Comment: hmmm any symbol/notation for this "domination"? I just googled but didn't find its definition. I'm just wondering if there is some standard notation for this element-wise comparison?

Comment: See [math overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510564/a-divide-and-conquer-algorithm-for-counting-dominating-points)